# Il (ne) possédait pas moins de quatorze calculatrices

Tags: négation

*Catastrophe à Huggagie City* d'Adam Cece :

> Ug Ugg adorait les maths. Ce sont des choses qui arrivent, me
> direz-vous. Sauf qu'Ug Ugg était un jeune troll de onze ans, et que
> les trolls, en règle générale, ça déteste les chiffres. La seule chose
> qui les intéresse, c'est de dégommer des trucs et des machins à coups
> de gourdin. Or, Urg ne possédait même pas de gourdin. En revanche, et
> au grand dam de sa vaste famille de trolls, il **ne** possédait **pas moins**
> de quatorze calculatrices.

Je pense qu'il faudrait écrire *il possédait **pas moins** de quatorze calculatrices* ou *il possédait **plus de** quatorze calculatrices*. C'est la phrase sans *ne* qui est correcte, non ?

Answer (score 4):

**Pas moins de** peut être compris de deux manières différentes suivant la manière dont il est prononcé.

1. Il **ne** possédait **pas moins** de quatorze calculatrices.

   1. Il avait **quatorze** calculatrices **ou plus**. (rare, prononciation différente avec *pas* et *moins* séparés). C'est la négation de *Il avait moins de quatorze calculatrices*.
   2. Il avait **exactement quatorze** calculatrices. (soutenu, *pas moins* est prononcé comme un seul mot). C'est une affirmation qui souligne le nombre élevé de calculatrices qu'il a.
2. Il possédait **pas moins** de quatorze calculatrices.

   Même alternative que précédemment :

   1. Il avait **quatorze** calculatrices **ou plus**. (relâché, rare, prononciation différente avec *pas* et *moins* séparés)
   2. Il avait **exactement quatorze** calculatrices. (anciennement parlé ou relâché, aujourd'hui courant)
3. Il possédait **plus** de quatorze calculatrices

   Il avait **quinze** calculatrices ou plus.

   Avec *plus*, on retrouve les mêmes formes: *Il **n'avait pas plus** de quatorze calculatrices* / *Il **avait pas plus** de quatorze calculatrices*. mais le sens *Il avait **au plus** quatorze calculatrices* est le plus courant.

Voir: http://bdl.oqlf.gouv.qc.ca/bdl/gabarit_bdl.asp?Th=2&t1=&id=4115

D'autre part, la phrase :

4. Il avait **pas mal** de calculatrices.

   ne prend pas de particule négative car ce n'est pas une négation, *pas mal* est ici une locution adverbiale de quantité signifiant "entre *assez* et *beaucoup*". Les formes *Il <s>n'avait pas mal</s> de calculatrices* et *Il avait <s>mal de</s> calculatrices* ne veulent rien dire.

Comment: Pour moi, c'est bizarre, car il n'y a pas de négation dans la phrase contenant _pas mal de_. Je pensais que c'était pareil pour _pas moins de_. Je pensais que _Il possédait pas moins de quatorze calculatrices_ = _Il avait 14 calculatrices ou plus_ et _Il ne possédait pas moins de quatorze calculatrices_ = son contraire _Il avait_... Ah, OK, je crois que j'ai compris, c'est pareil.

Comment: @Oreste Oui, *pas moins* se lexicalise en adverbe de quantité et perd alors son aspect négatif.

Comment: Il serait donc préférable d'omettre le _ne_, à mon avis, ce serait beaucoup plus logique.

Comment: @Oreste Oui, même [l'Académie](https://www.academie-francaise.fr/karine-e-france) qui n'est pourtant pas très avant-gardiste entérine *pas moins* sans ne.

Comment: Dans mon premier commentaire, j'ai dit que je comprenais cette logique. Là, je relis, et je dirais que non. Je ne comprends pas pourquoi il fallait écrire de cette façon, à l'envers, alors qu'il est possible de le faire d'une manière beaucoup plus simple.

Answer (score 1):

On pourrait croire que  la construction soutenue devrait comprendre la particule « ne », mais ce raisonnement est trompeur ; la subtilité reconnue par l'Académie devrait à mon (nouvel) avis être prise en compte.

[il ne possédait pas moins,il possédait pas moins](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=il+ne+poss%C3%A9dait+pas+moins%2Cil+poss%C3%A9dait+pas+moins&year_start=1800&year_end=2019&corpus=30&smoothing=3&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cil%20ne%20poss%C3%A9dait%20pas%20moins%3B%2Cc0#t1%3B%2Cil%20ne%20poss%C3%A9dait%20pas%20moins%3B%2Cc0)

[image]

Dans le parler familier on peut se passer de « ne ».

> ([antidote](https://www.antidote.info/fr/blogue/enquetes/pas-moins-de))
>
> D’autre part, dans son blogue² , l’Académie compare les deux phrases suivantes et indique sa préférence pour la première :
>
> - Ce travail a demandé pas moins de six mois.
> - Ce travail n’a pas demandé moins de six mois.
>
> L’interprétation à donner n’est pas explicitée, mais la durée de six mois doit probablement ici être entendue comme un nombre exact plutôt que comme une limite minimale.
>
> L’Académie donne aussi un exemple en fonction sujet :
>
> - Pas moins de cinq versions ont été nécessaires…
>
> On peut donc conclure que les deux constructions examinées sont acceptables, avec la nuance que la tournure sans ne implique généralement une interprétation exacte du nombre exprimé, accompagnée d’une certaine mise en relief sémantique. La construction avec ne est plus ambigüe, pouvant parfois revêtir cette même interprétation, mais par ailleurs signifiant souvent simplement « au moins ».
>
> *La chronique* Points de langue *ne compte pas moins de cent articles publiés*.

Donc, vous avez probablement raison ; il s'agit assez certainement de quatorze exactement, et « ne » ne devrait pas être utilisé.

² https://www.academie-francaise.fr/karine-e-france

Comment: Mais le sens de la phrase est _il possédait plus de quatorze calculatrices_. Dans _il possédait pas moins de quatorze calculatrices_, _pas_ est lié à _moins_ et non à _possédait_.

Comment: @Oreste Vous avez raison, la particule « ne » est en trop, et je modifie ma réponse.

Comment: Merci pour votre réponse détaillée. À mon avis, la phrase sans _ne_ est beaucoup plus logique. Les deux disent à peu près la même chose... mais pour comprendre la version avec _ne_ je dois réfléchir, ce n'est pas du tout naturel pour moi. Je suis d'accord avec Karine E.