# On n'est moins surpris qu'il se débrouille mal qu'on ne l'est qu'il y parvienne

Tags: négation

*Les embrouilles de Calma* de Barry Jonsberg :

Calma et Kiffo sont venus chez Jonno pour qu'il recueilles des informations au sujet du Pitbull, leur ennemi.

> -- Combien tu paies ?
>
> -- À toi de me le dire, Jonno.
>
> -- Ben ch'ais pas, laisse-moi réfléchir.
>
> Voilà qui promettait d'être intéressant. Un peu comme regarder un
> chien faire du vélo. On **n**'est **moins** surpris qu'il se débrouille mal
> qu'on **ne** l'est qu'il y parvienne.

Je comprends la dernière phrase grâce au contexte. Sinon, je la trouve très compliquée, j'ai du mal à saisir sa logique.

Donc, elle signifie *On est vraiment étonés de constater qu'un chien puisse faire du vélo. Il est maladroit, mais ce n'est guère surprenant* ? Si mon interprétation est correcte, comment faites-vous pour déchiffrer de telles structures ?

Peut-être qu'il s'agit d'une logique semblable à celle employée dans ce [fil](https://french.stackexchange.com/questions/49805/il-ne-poss%C3%A9dait-pas-moins-de-quatorze-calculatrices) ?

Comment: Ce la veut dire que la surprise serait plus grande de voir un chien bien faire du vélo alors qu’il serait moins surprenant qu’il en fasse mal. (J’espère que la réécriture est plus facile à comprendre.)

Comment: @PtitXav Merci :) Oui, j'ai compris, mais je pense qu'il ne fallait pas écrire le premier "ne". Le 2ème c'est un "ne" explitif. On m'a répondu sur "reddit".